# Creating new hosted buttons versus updating existing ones?

Tags: php, paypal

I need to dynamically generate the price of the full aggregate cart on my website - I've already built my own shopping cart. Only when the user is going to check out do I want to generate a button with the aggregate cart price.

What's a better approach? Should I create a hosted button through PayPal's interface and just update it whenever the user gets to the checkout stage? Or should I create a new button for every user checkout? Is either approach going to be more expensive than the other?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a saved hosted button for each item you sell. Because this way users can't tamper with the prices of the items.

If you use the "customized" button and change the form variables yourself without saving it on paypal, you'll have to verify the price of each order because frankly it is VERY easy to change them through DOM. (Especially true for anyone on this site)

If you have thousands of items, you might want to look into third-party merchant solutions that allows you to update items easier.

Comment: I suppose we would destroy buttons after using them, then? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/BM/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview#id093VD0JE0Y4